# Should I give as much C:/ space to Windows 10 as to Windows 7 if I have a system partition and a data partition?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, partitioning

I just bought a new laptop that has W10 on it and doing a clean install on it (my current computer dates back 2012 and has Windows 7). I usually have two partitions, one for system and one for data.

Over time, my W7 system partition got bloated by Windows install files and would easily reach the 100 Gb space (it didnt take up that much space initially of course). I couldn't reformat and re-install easily on my old laptop (VAIO Z - so the bios included ZERO basic component drivers and installing them in the wrong order could just mess up the computer and require a re-install)

So I'm jumping from 2012 to 2016 now, I see that UEFI is 'replacing' the BIOS and MBR is being replaced by GPT. Honestly, I've never heard these terms until today, but it seems like an upgrade in managing partitions and such from what I read. Enough to know I should use these standards (about a whole evening to figure out how to install W8 with these formats).

Now that I know to configure my computer using these formats, the question:

Should I still allocate 100 Gb and expect it to be bloated with installation files over time, or the increase in technology somehow doesn't need me to allocate such a big space anymore ?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 takes up basically the same amount of space as Windows 7. I assume your installation was taking up close to 100gb not because of Windows but because of software you installed overtime. Unless you specify for every piece of software you install to be elsewhere, it's going to be on your C: drive. Personally, I never make my C: drive less than 100gb. Windows 10 itself takes up about ~30gb and future updates will make that rise. You could drop it some if you would like from 100gb but I would recommend not doing so, HDD space is too cheap these days to worry about a few gb.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Actually the softwares don't take that much space. My C:/ used to be 90 GB, of which W7 takes up 60 GB and 30 Gb of the 60 GB is the installer folder. I read that W7 keeps a lot of garbage in the installer folder. Just wondered if they managed to do it better for W10 :)